# Is it wish or wishes?

Tags: grammar

Which is correct?
Everyone here at xyz wish you a happy holiday or 
everyone here at xyz wishes you a happy holiday?

Comment: _Each_ and _every_ are singular, but _all_ is plural. _Some, any,_ and _none_ can be either, depending.

Answer (score 2):

**It´s "wishes"**, since it is in third person (Everyone), so the correct way to say it is: *Everyone here at xyz wishes you a happy holiday*.

> -es2
>   SUFFIX
>   1 Forming the third person singular of the present tense in verbs ending  in sibilant sounds.
>   ‘pushes’
>   2 Forming the third
>   person singular of the present tense in verbs ending in -o   (but not
>   -oo)   ‘goes’

So either way with the subject being "everyone" it is only correct to use **"wishes"** (verb)

Source from [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/-es)!

Comment: Good job for adding a source, but the quote is not very legible. Try using "> " and looking at the preview at the bottom of the page before posting. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It should be either

> Everyone (here at ...) wishes you [...]

since "everyone" is 3rd person singular, or

> We (at ...) wish you [...]

since "we" is 1st person plural.

Comment: Not sure why this answer was down-voted. Perhaps the “1nd”. Change it to 1st and perhaps you’ll have better luck.

Comment: @David Not sure here either, but thanks for pointing it out!